# How to search and append text to a value in Google Sheets?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import contents from URL using `importxml` in Google Sheets and use `regexextract` to filter the result to include only digits (decimal or whole).

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(D25,"//element/"),"(\d+)")
```

Now I want to append text after filtering like adding `$` sign to digits so instead of `9.0` it'll become `9.0 USD`. But I'm not sure how to go about this as I am not that familiar with regex.

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
=TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(D25, "//element/"), "(\d+)"), "#.00 $")
```

or like:

```
=TEXT(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(D25, "//element/"), "(\d+)"), "#.00")&" USD"
```